# Wireshark capture SSL only

Tags: ssl, wireshark

I would like to capture SSL or HTTPS traffic only in Wireshark, this is not something that can be filtered after due to the length of the time I would be recording the data after and the size of the .pcap file.

There are capture only filters for TCP or UDP (tcp port http) for example.

I have configured it to use `tcp port https` but it sill seems to have other unrelated junk data. Is there a better way of capturing HTTPs/SSL data?

---

Bonus, can I dump this to a network disk instead of pcap'in and storing on the same box?

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of junk data in the capture?

Comment: Sure, there is random TCP data that I can not follow (using follow SSL stream). I would like to not have any data except HTTPS data over TCP not all TCP data and TCP HTTPS data.
 
I know I could capture just 443 but that would not include HTTPS over arbitrary ports correct?
<p>
**edit so double enter posts. Here is an example of the standard TCP traffic I want to ignore:
 
TCP Src Port: 49623 , Dst Port 443

Comment: But, is the data to or from TCP port 443?  The filter you're using is going to capture anything involving that port.  Maybe the filter you want is `ssl`?

Comment: SSL only as a filter is legitimate only after mass capture. I need it on pre capture.

Comment: [link](http://pb.nervesocket.com:88/1IbMaojw.png) Working filter for TCP HTTPS

Comment: [link] (http://pb.nervesocket.com:88/1IbQF9Wb.png) Non working SSL filter

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is that HTTPS traffic that travels over the Internet is confidential, a random router or person who happens to capture your packages cannot decrypt the HTTPS without the decryption key.
So bottom line: Wireshark cannot decrypt HTTPS traffic.